# Using php to rewrite the URL for refreshing issues

Tags: php, url

I know. I KNOW. OK? The way I have coded and put together my user management system is terrible. Im using actions. Now normally you would have another page handle the actions then redirect to the main page with the data but I havent done that. So currently, this is what occurs,

`http://www.domain.com/index.php?action=newUser&id=1028`

is refreshed and returns the error "That user already exists". Which is not that big of a deal. However.

`http://www.domain.com/createblogpost.php?action=postNew`

When the above is refreshed it results in a reproduced, identical post.

Is there a function or way I can get the php, at the end of the `action=postNew` code snippet that would have the URL rewrote to `www.domain.com/createblogpost.php` which would stop refresh injection.

Any ideas? Or any new paradigms of thought I havent considered?
(inb4 dont code like a joke)

Thanks in advance,
Aleski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the `Location` header...

```
header('Location: http://example.com/somewhere-else');
```

This pattern is known as [*Post/Redirect/Get*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: I need the browser to remain in the same place, but simply edit the URL bar so that when they press refresh (F5) the browser thinks its somewhere else and doesnt refresh the `action=update` part.

Comment: @Aleski I hope that browsers don't allow you to do that, because it would make it too easy for phishing sites to mislead consumers as to which site they're currently at. This was asked a long time ago: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: www.domain.com/createblogpost.php');
```

Comment: I need the browser to remain in the same place, but simply edit the URL bar so that when they press refresh (F5) the browser thinks its somewhere else and doesnt refresh the action=update part